# In VMware with macOS Big Sur, it kicks me login screen continuously

Tags: macos, icloud, macos-big-sur

I don't know it is the reason of my problem or not. But after I logged into my iCloud account, in a minute Big Sur kicked me to the login screen and asked password again. I thought it's fine. I entered my password and logged in again. But homescreen stucked and it kicks me back to the login screen again. And it continue like that.

Is there any solution for that? And is the problem logging into my iCloud account? If it is, is there any way to use iCloud and Apple services in VMware without any problem?

Comment: Have you solved it ?